# On the prime divisors of two numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory

We know that $q=p^a$ and $q'=p'^b$ are odd  prime powers and $p$ and $p'$ are of the form $4k+1$. Also $p\mid (q'^2+1)$  and $p'\mid (q^2+1)$. If $\pi(n)$ denotes the set of prime divisors of $n$, is it possible that the following relations are hold:

(1)   $\pi(q^2-1)=\pi(q'^2-1)$

and

(2)   $\pi(q^2+1)\cup \{p\}=\pi(q'^2+1)\cup \{p'\}$

We suspect that this is impossible but we can not prove it.

Comment: Have you done any computations? Why do you suspect that it is impossible?

Comment: Dear Nick we try to find any answer but using computer we can not get any answer for them.

Comment: You may want to add the gt.group-theory tag - I guess this question is motivated by finding different groups $PSL_2(q)$ and $PSL_2(q')$ whose orders have the same prime divisors (?).

Comment: if you've used computers, do you know, for instance, that this situation does not occur for $q$ and $q'$ both less than 1000 or something?

Comment: Yes this is the same problem in Group Theory that you stated with some more conditions. For your second question we check just special cases because of the limitation of our computer.

Comment: Stormer's theorem on consecutive smooth numbers may be enough to show that 1) happens only finitely many times for a given set of primes. It might serve you well to look at arbitrary squares $s^2$ and relate two of them  by the prime factors of $s^2 +- 1$.